# Java displaying and using array lists

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have a question on how to use and display array lists. In my case, I think I am using the array lists correctly because the compiler doesn't complain. But when I display it, an error comes up that looks like this:

```
run:
Average Monthly Electricity Bill:                             463.26
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f !=  java.util.ArrayList
Average Monthly Electricity Price Per Kilowatt:     at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2761)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2708)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
at CO2FromElectricityTester.main(CO2FromElectricityTester.java:72)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
public class CO2FromElectricityTester {

public static void main(String args[]){

    // declare & initialize variables
    double months = 3.0;
    double emissionFactor = 1.37;
    int kilowattHoursSept = 109;
    int kilowattHoursOct = 87;
    int kilowattHoursNov = 93;
    double monthlyCostSept = 551.51;
    double monthlyCostOct = 392.84;
    double monthlyCostNov = 445.42;
    double avgKilowattHours = (kilowattHoursSept + kilowattHoursOct + 
            kilowattHoursNov) / 3;
    double avgMonthlyCost = (monthlyCostSept + monthlyCostOct + 
            monthlyCostNov) / 3;

    // create object
    CO2FromElectricity CO2 = new CO2FromElectricity();

    // // // declare & initialize variables for methods

    // // create array lists
    ArrayList<Double> monthlyPriceForElec = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> monthlyElectricBill = new ArrayList<Double>();

    // average monthly price for electricity
    double avgPricePerKilowatt = CO2.calcPricePerKilowatt(avgKilowattHours, 
            avgMonthlyCost);

    // average monthly electric bill
    double avgCO2Emission = CO2.calcCO2Emission(emissionFactor, months, 
            avgMonthlyCost, avgPricePerKilowatt);

    // initialize array lists
    monthlyPriceForElec.add(avgPricePerKilowatt);
    monthlyElectricBill.add(avgCO2Emission);

    // display results
    System.out.printf("%1s%34.2f%n", "Average Monthly Electricity Bill: ", 
            avgMonthlyCost);
    System.out.printf("%1s%20.2f%n", "Average Monthly Electricity Price Per "
            + "Kilowatt: ", monthlyPriceForElec);
    System.out.printf("%1s%10.2f%n", "CO2 Emissions from Electricity Usage "
            + "in a 3 Month Period: ", monthlyElectricBill);
}

}
```

If it helps, below is my other file for declaring the methods:

```
public class CO2FromElectricity {

// default constructor
CO2FromElectricity(){

}

// method for calculating price per kilowatt
public double calcPricePerKilowatt(double kilowattHours, double monthlyCost){
    return monthlyCost / kilowattHours;
}

// method for calculating CO2 emission
public double calcCO2Emission(double emissionFactor, double months, 
        double avgMonthlyCost, double avgPricePerKilowatt){
    return (avgMonthlyCost / avgPricePerKilowatt) * emissionFactor * months;
}

}
```

Comment: You are trying to print a list using printf saying that the format is a float, incompatible types

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. You're trying to format an ArrayList where you have a floating point format specified. Your question is a little unclear, but instead of

```
System.out.printf("%1s%20.2f%n", "Average Monthly Electricity Price Per "
        + "Kilowatt: ", monthlyPriceForElec); // you want the result
```

I think you want

```
System.out.printf("%1s%20.2f%n", "Average Monthly Electricity Price Per "
        + "Kilowatt: ", avgPricePerKilowatt); // like this
```

Then on your next line you want `avgCO2Emission` not `monthlyElectricBill`.

If you wanted to print the entire list you would need to Iterate the lists respectively.

Comment: Then what is the sense to have arrayList? i think he want to do `printf` with the list

Answer (score 0):

Asside, not part of an answer.
Use interfaces not concrete classes.
Don't do this:

```
 ArrayList<Double> monthlyPriceForElec = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Do this instead:

```
List<Double> monthlyPriceForElec = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

A list (including an ArrayList) is a collection of data.
Display the contents of a list by looping through the list and displaying each element.

```
List<Double> hooty = new ArrayList<Double>();
... put stuff in hooty.
for (Double blammy : hooty)
{
    System.out.printf("blammy not hooty: %20.2f", blammy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.printf does not have special support for Collections, it will treat it as a regular object (not Iterable).  If you want to format the items inside of your collection, you'll need to loop over them and call System.out.printf() on each item.

Answer (score 0):

Where you did your print statements, you put “System.out.printf”. I think you’re meant to to put “System.out.println” otherwise the compiler just has a massive brain fart. I think that’s the error but I’m not sure. Try changing the “f” part of your print statements to “ln” and see if that works.

Comment: `System.out.printf()` is valid Java. See [Print Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)